# $PQ:2x+y+6=0$ is a chord hyperbola $x^2-4y^2=4$, and $R=(\alpha,\beta)$ with $\alpha^2+\beta^2-1\leq0$, such that area of triangle $PQR$ is minimum.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> Let $PQ: 2x+y+6=0$ is a chord of the curve $x^2 - 4 y^2 = 4$. Coordinates of the point $R(\alpha,\beta)$ that satisfy $\alpha^2+\beta^2-1 \leq 0$, such that area of triangle $PQR$ is minimum ; are given by :

I have tried finding out the points of contact of the hyperbola but for the given equations the points are lengthy to find.

I have also considered drawing a line segment perpendicular to point P to the circle where there which can give minimum area of the triangle

This is a JEE Problem (High-school Level) Where we get 3 Minutes time to solve. Any easily approachable Answer is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: Hint:  Plot the curve and the straight line, find $P$ and $Q$, and plot the given region of point $R$, see where you should pick $R$ to minimize the area of triangle $PQR$.  Once you convince yourself, derive the visual result algebraically.

Comment: @GeometryLover I Have tried finding out the points P and Q, But the Quadratic equation which we get has irrational Roots

Comment: No, I meant find them on the graph (or sketch).  As pointed out by the solution beneath, the exact values of $P$ and $Q$ are irrelevant, because the triangle base $PQ$ is fixed.  Only the distance of point $R$ from the line $PQ$ is what's important here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint1:** All the different triangles have the same base. So the one with the least area has the least height.

**Hint2:** Find the normal of the circle whose slope is perpendicular to the line

Note that you don't have to find $P,Q$

[Graph](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/ck6aabac?embed) for reference